# Capybara with js: true not finding checkbox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, rspec, capybara-webkit

I need to test if Javascript alert is being displayed in validation proccess after checking one checkbox. 
I'm using `RSpec`, `Capybara` with `Webkit` and `Database Cleaner`.

My test without `JS: true` :

```
  it "alerts to choose two players" do
    set_and_visit
    first("input[type='checkbox']").set(true)
    expect(page).to have_content('Remember that you must choose two players to start a game.')
  end
```

Finds a checkbox but cannot find the alert message.

When I add JS - `"alerts to choose two players", js: true do` it returns an error

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `set' for nil:NilClass
```

I've tried using `check 'John Doe'` and `first("input[type='checkbox']").check` but it still didn't work.

Comment: can we see the content of the page this test is operating on?

Comment: @sevenseacat my `page.body` was empty the whole time as it turned out I made a mistake with url and was pointing to a non-existing page. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, silly as it sounds the mistake I made was in a url - in my `set_and_visit` method I was `visiting 'matches/new'` instead of `'/matches/new'`. When tested, `puts page.bod`y was returning an empty string because it couldn't find that url.
Still I'm not sure why test including `check 'John Doe'` wasn't returning any error like the one with `js: true`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible issues that seem likely:

### Asynchronous Issues

The default driver (rack-test) is synchronous, so the page will always be fully loaded by the time you run `first`. When using asynchronous drivers like capybara-webkit, you need to watch out for race conditions. The page may still be loading (or updating via Ajax) when `first` is called, so the `input` element may not have appeared yet.

**Solution:** use `find("input[type='checkbox']").set(true)` instead of `first`. This will cause Capybara to wait up to two seconds for the `input` to appear before giving up and raising an error, instead of immediately returning `nil`.

I wrote more about writing asynchronous tests in a [blog post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/write-reliable-asynchronous-integration-tests-with-capybara).

### Hidden Elements

Because the default driver (rack-test) doesn't parse CSS or run JavaScript, it doesn't understand which elements are hidden or visible. This means that you can interact with hidden elements that real users can't click on or fill in.

On the other hand, drivers like capybara-webkit know which elements are actually visible to the user. By default, Capybara ignores all elements that it knows are hidden.

**Solution:** use `find("input[type='checkbox']", visible: false).set(true)`

Note that this won't work if the element is actually visible, and that it's probably better to figure out why the element is hidden. After all, if capybara-webkit can't find it, your users probably can't, either.

You can read more about how Capybara handles visibility on the [elabs blog](http://www.elabs.se/blog/60-introducing-capybara-2-1).

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help! I was considering hidden elements and will familiarize myself with your notes but the answer to my problem was... A typo. I was pointing to wrong URL so my `page.body` was empty the whole time. Thanks anyways :)